# Oracle insert timestamp - AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, date-formatting

In SQL Developer I have created an export, .sql file, (a really big one). It contains hundreds of inserts like :

```
"Insert into SCHEMA.TABLE (
 ... ,
 CREATEDATE,
 MODIFIEDDATE,
 ....
) 
values (
 ... , 
 to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
 to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'),
 ...
);"
```

When I run it in SQL Developer, it works fine. But I can't import a bit .sql file with SQL Developer (or I don't know how to do it).

When I run it with SQL*Plus I get following error:

> ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required

When I remove the AM/PM keywords from the insert, SQL*Plus can insert row, with them, no luck. What is the problem with AM / PM?

Here is the exact insert command:

```
Insert into SCHEMA.TABLE(

ENTRYID,GROUPID,COMPANYID,USERID,USERNAME,CREATEDATE,MODIFIEDDATE,
CLASSNAMEID,CLASSPK,CLASSUUID,VISIBLE,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,PUBLISHDATE,
EXPIRATIONDATE,MIMETYPE,TITLE,DESCRIPTION,SUMMARY,URL,HEIGHT,WIDTH,
PRIORITY,VIEWCOUNT

) values (

11902,11005,10136,10178,'Test Test',
to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),
to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'),
10076,11900,'AAA',1,null,null,null,null,null,
'ABC','XyZ',null,null,0,0,0,2563

);
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with AM/PM; inserting that `to_timestamp()` call into a table with a `timestamp` columns works fine in SQL*Plus. The AM/PM literal values are not affected by NLS settings as far as I'm aware so I don't think that could be the issue. I have to assume you've posted *exactly* what you're running; the full command without changed names would give a bit more confidence though, along with the amended version that works. What's the problem with SQL Developer; you can open a script file and then 'run script'?

Comment: Can you post a sample of data from the SQL file? Is it always using the `'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'` format for times or does it always/sometimes use `'DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF'`?

Comment: Huh, turns out that the meridian indicator is NLS-sensitive. What does `select value from nls_session_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE'` give you in SQL*Plus? Hopefully not English; and Slovak would be a good answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only immediate way I can see to reproduce this is to change the NLS setings; but not `NLS_LANGUAGE` as that would affect the error message as well. Using English is OK as you'd expect:

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='ENGLISH';

Session altered.

SQL> select value from nls_session_parameters
  2  where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE';

VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENGLISH

SQL> insert into t42 (createddate)
  2  values (to_timestamp('20-08-12 01.09.53.271000000 AM','DD-MM-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'));

1 row created.
```

Changing just the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` reproduces your error:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='SLOVAK';

Session altered.

SQL> insert into t42 (createddate)
  2  values (to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'));
values (to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'))
                     *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-01855: AM/A.M. or PM/P.M. required
```

Changing `NLS_LANGUAGE`, directly or through something that influences it, would make the error message appear differently as well:

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE = 'SLOVAK';

Relácia zmenená.

SQL> insert into t42 (createddate)
  2  values (to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'));
values (to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000 AM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'))
                     *
ERROR v riadku 2:
ORA-01855: vy¿aduje sa AM/A.M. alebo PM/P.M.
```

You'd need a language that still recognises `AUG` as a valid month, but doesn't use `AM`/`PM`; Slovak seems to fit the bill, so I'd guess that might be where you're from. Other languages may do the same too. Bit strange that the error message when `NLS_LANGUAGE` is still set shows AM/PM, to but `to_char(sysdate, 'HH AM')` indicates that message is wrong. With only `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` set the message is in English anyway (try it with Turkish, for example, but you'd have to change the month name or switch use month numbers) and it always shows AM/PM.

If that is what's happening, either change the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` to English before running this script; or change your SQL Developer settings to use Slovak (or whatever you actually use) before doing the export - which would hopefully make the export use `DOPOLUDNIE`/`POPOLUDNIE`, though it wouldn't entirely surprise me if it didn't; or change the SQL Developer `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` to use 24-hour time (and a 4-digit year, and month numbers instead of names) for the export, which would avoid the issue entirely. Or run the script from SQL Developer, of course.

Comment: Thank guys !!! Adding this "alter session set NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='ENGLISH';" help me ... thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer describes the problem very well; there is a simpler solution though, if you're able to change your generated insert statements slightly. [`TO_TIMESTAMP()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions213.htm#SQLRF51921) has a third parameter, which lets you specify the NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE in the insert itself.

```
create table a ( tstamp timestamp );

Table created.

insert into a
values (to_timestamp( '20-08-12 01.09.53.271000000 AM'
                    , 'DD-MM-RR HH.MI.SS.FF PM'
                    , 'nls_date_language = ENGLISH'));

1 row created.

select *
  from a;

TSTAMP
------------------------------------------------------
20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000
```

You don't then need to alter the date language for the session, or alter it back afterwards.

Comment: If they're coming from an SQL Developer 'export' then it would be a bit of a pain to go through and modify them all, but yes, good alternative.

Comment: I wouldn't know @Alex... I'd hope that Oracle's tools would allow you to use Oracle but I've been wrong about that in the past :-).

Answer (score 0):

Without any data to look at I can't be sure but it sound like your "big SQL file" does not always (or sometimes) have the time stamps in the format you are expecting and is not using `AM` or `PM`.

Try using a 24-hour clock rather than `AM` or `PM` and see if that matches the data in the "big SQL file":

```
 ...
 to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 01.09.53.271000000','DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF'),
 to_timestamp('20-AUG-12 13.09.53.271000000','DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SS.FF'),
 ...
```